# Content Query Web Part - display certain section of list

Tags: list, content-query-web-part

I want to have a web part which displays data from a Sharepoint list. I have tried to do this using the Content Query Web Part by displaying the results in descending order using the 'Created' column, so it shows the most recent items. I will be limiting this to 5 items.

**However**, I do not want the web part to show the five **most recent** items. Instead, want it to show items 6,7,8,9 and 10 from the list. Can someone explain how it would be possible to do this?

Comment: You can modify the elements to show by using javascript. For example, you can set up your CQWP to get the top 10 and hide the first 5 elements.

Comment: Cheers Dan - that seems the best route to go down. Any tips on writing that bit of code?

Comment: it depends on the code your template. I cannot help you if you don't provide the html.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the Sharepoint REST api, where you need to make a http call with a query which is very easy to filter and sort the results. It should look something like this

*/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('**List_Name**')/items $select=**Col1**,**Col2**&$filter=Created ge '**5**'&$orderby=Created desc&$top=**5**"*

Replace the values in bold with your desired ones if you wish to use this method. I believe this will retrieve the data that you are looking for.

You must use javascript to make the http call and to use the retrieved data.
I suggest you to check on google about Get sharepoint list data using angular.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display items with an ID (or any other numeric field for that matter) within a given range, you can use the "Additional Filters" section of the Content Query Web Part to add that constraint:

[image: CQWP filters]